# How to add default values to nested items in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, strong-parameters

In the Sign up form of my Rails 6 application an `Account` with a nested `User` can be created.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.users.build(
      :owner => true,
      :language => "FR"
    )
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Account created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def account_params
    safe_attributes = [
      :name,
      :users_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :owner, :language]
    ]
    params.require(:account).permit(*safe_attributes)
  end

end
```

What is the best way to define **default values** on the new `user` here?

Right now, I use `hidden_fields` for the default values in my sign up form thus making them publicly available. This is of course *not* what I want because it's very insecure.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

I know that there's [Rails' with_defaults](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-with_defaults) method but I couldn't get it to work on **nested items** so far.

Comment: Please elaborate on what kind of defaults you want to set and if the defaults are always the same or if they depend on the associated account. Would it be an option to configure the default on database level?

Comment: @spickermann, the defaults depend on the situation. A `user` may also be created in another controller and the `owner` attribute should be `false` then. That's why I can't set the defaults on database level I guess.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
account_params[:users_attributes] = account_params[:users_attributes].with_defaults({ first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith'})
```

in first line of create action

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get this to work. It doesn't change anything if I include that line. It seems that Rails simply ignores it. The attributes are empty in the database after creating a new record.